# React Lazy loading with old UI in place along with loading spinner

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, lazy-loading, react-suspense

I am using lazy loading in React, when lazy load starts, along with loading spinner that is used inside **Suspense**, I also need to **keep the old UI in place** and update the UI when the loading is done.

Right now I am losing the old UI but able to see the loading spinner, I need both old UI and loading spinner to show. How to achieve this in React functional approach or Hooks.

Comment: Can you please provide some code? What you're trying to do can be achieved with React 18 `startTransition` but it depends on the conditions in which your lazy loaded component will be rendered.